# Send sms through d-link GSM modem in PHP

Tags: php, sms, gsm

I am trying to send sms via D-Link GSM modem. I am new on this. My code shows **Unable to setup COM port** I did not add any additional file, library or any modification in php.ini file in xampp. just installed software provided by modem. My operating system is windows 10. I am mentioning my code, though I got it from internet.

```
 $mobile_number=$_POST['mobile_number'];
 $messages=$_POST['messages'];

$gsm_send_sms = new gsm_send_sms();
$gsm_send_sms->debug = false;
$gsm_send_sms->port = 'COM3';
$gsm_send_sms->baud = 115200;
$gsm_send_sms->init();

$status = $gsm_send_sms->send($mobile_number,$messages);
if ($status) {
echo "<body bgcolor='lightgreen'>";
echo "<br><br><br>";
echo "<h3 align='center'>Message Successfully Send... </h3>\n";
echo "</body>";
} else {
 echo "<body bgcolor='lightgreen'>";
 echo "<br><br><br>";
echo "<h3 align='center'>Message not sent Successfully... </h3>\n";
echo "</body>";
}


 $gsm_send_sms->close();


 //Send SMS via serial SMS modem
 class gsm_send_sms {

public $port = 'COM3';
public $baud = 115200;

public $debug = false;

private $fp;
private $buffer;

//Setup COM port
public function init() {

    $this->debugmsg("Setting up port: \"{$this->port} @ \"{$this->baud}\" baud");

    exec("MODE {$this->port}: BAUD={$this->baud} PARITY=N DATA=8 STOP=1", $output, $retval);

    if ($retval != 0) {
        throw new Exception('Unable to setup COM port, check it is correct');
    }

    $this->debugmsg(implode("\n", $output));

    $this->debugmsg("Opening port");

    //Open COM port
    $this->fp = fopen($this->port . ':', 'r+');

    //Check port opened
    if (!$this->fp) {
        throw new Exception("Unable to open port \"{$this->port}\"");
    }

    $this->debugmsg("Port opened");
    $this->debugmsg("Checking for response from modem");

    //Check modem connected
    fputs($this->fp, "AT\r");

    //Wait for ok
    $status = $this->wait_reply("OK\r\n", 5);

    if (!$status) {
        throw new Exception('Did not receive responce from modem');
    }

    $this->debugmsg('Modem connected');

    //Set modem to SMS text mode
    $this->debugmsg('Setting text mode');
    fputs($this->fp, "AT+CMGF=1\r");

    $status = $this->wait_reply("OK\r\n", 5);

    if (!$status) {
        throw new Exception('Unable to set text mode');
    }

    $this->debugmsg('Text mode set');

}

//Wait for reply from modem
private function wait_reply($expected_result, $timeout) {

    $this->debugmsg("Waiting {$timeout} seconds for expected result");

    //Clear buffer
    $this->buffer = '';

    //Set timeout
    $timeoutat = time() + $timeout;

    //Loop until timeout reached (or expected result found)
    do {

        $this->debugmsg('Now: ' . time() . ", Timeout at: {$timeoutat}");

        $buffer = fread($this->fp, 1024);
        $this->buffer .= $buffer;

        usleep(200000);//0.2 sec

        $this->debugmsg("Received: {$buffer}");

        //Check if received expected responce
        if (preg_match('/'.preg_quote($expected_result, '/').'$/', $this->buffer)) {
            $this->debugmsg('Found match');
            return true;
            //break;
        } else if (preg_match('/\+CMS ERROR\:\ \d{1,3}\r\n$/', $this->buffer)) {
            return false;
        }

    } while ($timeoutat > time());

    $this->debugmsg('Timed out');

    return false;

}

//Print debug messages
private function debugmsg($message) {

    if ($this->debug == true) {
        $message = preg_replace("%[^\040-\176\n\t]%", '', $message);
        echo $message . "\n";
    }

}

//Close port
public function close() {

    $this->debugmsg('Closing port');

    fclose($this->fp);

}

//Send message
public function send($tel, $message) {

    //Filter tel
    $tel = preg_replace("%[^0-9\+]%", '', $tel);

    //Filter message text
    $message = preg_replace("%[^\040-\176\r\n\t]%", '', $message);

    $this->debugmsg("Sending message \"{$message}\" to \"{$tel}\"");

    //Start sending of message
    fputs($this->fp, "AT+CMGS=\"{$tel}\"\r");

    //Wait for confirmation
    $status = $this->wait_reply("\r\n> ", 5);

    if (!$status) {
        //throw new Exception('Did not receive confirmation from modem');
        $this->debugmsg('Did not receive confirmation from modem');
        return false;
    }

    //Send message text
    fputs($this->fp, $message);

    //Send message finished indicator
    fputs($this->fp, chr(26));

    //Wait for confirmation
    $status = $this->wait_reply("OK\r\n", 180);

    if (!$status) {
        //throw new Exception('Did not receive confirmation of message sent');
        $this->debugmsg('Did not receive confirmation of message sent');
        return false;
    }

    $this->debugmsg("Message Send Successfully...");

    return true;

  }
}
```

Comment: Is the modem on COM3?  Maybe COM1?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Also tried with COM1. not working

Comment: What if you check with `right click to "This PC"` -> `Manage` -> `Device Manager` -> `Ports (COM & LPT)`? You device's COM port should appear there, if correctly connected to PC (and to power supply). Furthermore you can click on properties in order to have more info about that COM.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Here I found **debug port(COM7) NMEA device(COM8) speech port(COM10)** I also tried with 7,8,10 . still not working

Answer (score 0):

It's Look like You are using a D-Link **USB** GSM Modem.
in this case Modem COM port doesn't show in **Device Manager** Automatically.
First you must start **D-Link Connection Manager** **SoftWare**  and then you can find your modem under **MODEM** category in **Device Manager**.
**R-Click** on it and Open **Properties window**.
You can find **COM port** on it!

[image: GSM Modem]

[image: COM port]